# insert multiple rows to database

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have multiple rows insertion, so, i want to insert them into database.
i am trying to use loop function to send them to a table; but not success. Please anyone help with this?

```js
//Adding New Line Item Function
 var i = 1;
 function AddNew(){
  if (i <=3){ //if you don't want limit, you remove IF condition
    i++;
    var div= document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = '<input type="text" value="'+i+'" name="lineitem_'+i+'" maxlength="2" size="2"> <input type="text" name="materialcode_'+i+'" placeholder="Material Code" maxlength="18" size="18"> <input type="text" name="qty_'+i+'" placeholder="Quantity" maxlength="10" size="10"> <input type="text" name="price_'+i+'" placeholder="Price" maxlength="10" size="10"> <input type="button" onclick="removeItem(this)" value="-">';
    document.getElementById('addingitem').appendChild(div);
  }
 }
 
 function removeItem(div){
  //document.getElementById('addingitem').removeChild(div.parentNode);
  i--;
  var addingitem = document.getElementById('addingitem');
  addingitem.removeChild(div.parentNode);
  var inputs = addingitem.querySelectorAll('[name^="lineitem_"]');
  for (var r = 0; r < inputs.length; r++) 
  {
   var item = inputs[r];
   item.value = r + 1;
  }
    inputs = null;
 }
 //Validate Number Key
 function isNumberKey(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
    return !(charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57));
 }
```

```html
<form method="post" action="make_order.php">
              <!--Adding item-->
                Item Detail:
                <br />
                <div id="addingitem">
                    <input type="text" name="lineitem_1" id="item" value="1" maxlength="2" size="2">
                    <input type="text" name="materialcode_1" placeholder="Material Code" maxlength="18" size="18">
                    <input type="text" name="qty_1" placeholder="Quantity" maxlength="10" size="10">
                    <input type="text" name="price_1" placeholder="Price" maxlength="10" size="10">
                    <input type="button" name="addnew" id="Add_New()" onClick="AddNew()" value="New Item">
                </div>
                <br />
        <input type="submit" name="makeorder" value="Make Order">
     </form>
```

Comment: Send them to what table? And where is php code, d'you have it?

Comment: //insert into database-Line Item Data
 for ($i=1; $i<5; $i++)
 {
  //$lineitem_1 = $_POST['lineitem_1'$i];
  $materialcode_1 = $_POST['materialcode_'.$i];
  $sql_lineitem = "INSERT INTO tbl_order_item (material) values ('".$materialcode_1."')";
  
  if (msqli_query($con, $sql_lineitem))
  {
   echo "Success";
  }else
  {
   echo "Fail: ".$sql_lineitem;
  }
  
 }

Comment: @Ratana You are using `for ($i=1; $i<5; $i++) ` , is count for textboxes is fixed?

Comment: i count textbox only 4, you can reference code snippet.